# How to simplify Razor Class Library inclusion in ASP.Net Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, razor-class-library

Previously, in ASP.Net Core 2.2 I had the following in my Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Any referenced Razor Class Libraries automatically showed up with their controllers on the proper paths (by attribute routing in the controllers), which rendered their proper views.

Now, I've upgraded everything to ASP.Net Core 3.0, and my Startup now looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(MyRazorClassLibrary).Assembly)
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

The `Configure()` method is according the the spec, but the `ConfigureServices()` suddenly has a lot of extra "baggage". Everything seemingly works, but it seems like such a hassle to have to manually add the Razor Class Library assembly (I have several, and it makes for much less maintainable code). Previously all views were also automatically found, but now I have to use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet package in order for the application to be able to find the views in the RCL.

Are there any easier ways to use Razor Class Libraries with their own views and controllers in ASP.Net Core 3.0?